# java deserialize exception

Tags: java, serialization, exception

ive got a problem with deserializing at the beginning of the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

        Test object = new Test(); // Test implements Serializable

        //start
        deserialize();  

        //do something

        //end
        serialize(object);         
    }

public static void deserialize()
    {
        test object = null;

        try
          {
             FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream(".../Example.ser");
             if(file.read()!=-1) //the first time the file will be empty
             {
                 ObjectInputStream read= new ObjectInputStream(file); //here an exception is thrown the second time the program is started
                 object  = (Test) read.readObject();
                 object .printdata();
                 read.close();
                 file.close();
             }
             else
             {
                 file.close(); 
             }
          }catch(IOException i)
          {
             i.printStackTrace();
             return;
          }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
          {
             c.printStackTrace();
             return;
          } 
    }

    public static void serialize(Test object)
    {   
        try
        {
           FileOutputStream file =
           new FileOutputStream(".../Example.ser");
           ObjectOutputStream write = new ObjectOutputStream(file );
           write .writeObject(object);
           write .close();
           file .close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the program works if would switch serialize and deserialize or if i call deserialize after serialize.
it runs fine the first time but if i start it a second time deserialize @  ObjectInputStream read= new ObjectInputStream(file); throws an streamcorrupted exception.

at program start the serialize file has to be deserialized and printed and as i said if switch the calls and then copy the call of deserialize back to the top it works but not if it stays like that. the first time it runs but the second time the exception is thrown.

Comment: Test Class don't have any variables to store in the .ser file? Have you initialised them in Test class itself?. what is the value you have in the object that was put for serialization

Comment: Try `FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(".../Example.ser",false);` when you serialize to empty the file.

Comment: Do you have the .ser file generated on that path. you will get streamcorrupted exception when you dont have that .ser file

Comment: @KalaiarasanManimaran No, he will get `FileNotFoundException` if the file doesn't exist. You can't get any kind a stream whether corrupt or otherwise from a non-existent file.

Comment: @PabloGallegoFalcón `new FileOutputStream(String)` is equivalent to `new FileOutputStream(String, boolean)` when the second parameter is false.

Comment: @PabloGallegoFalcón in the object is a "List <String> list = new ArrayList <String>()" which is filled with numbers. the test class has this array list, the constructor is only super().

Answer (score 2):

```
if(file.read()!=-1) //the first time the file will be empty
```

The problem is here. You are reading and throwing away the first byte of the file, so the following reads will be out of sync. Remove it. The comment isn't correct either. The first time you run this code, the file will be *absent*, not empty. If you still need to test for a zero-length file, just catch `EOFException` separately, as you're only reading one object.

Comment: thanks now the error is gone but the serializing is not working now. it seems when i start the program again, the values are overwritten and the old ones are gone.

Comment: You'll need to start a new question for that.

Comment: cant that be answered here? why do i have to create a new question

Comment: You're not suppose to ask multiple questions and you're certainly not supposed to ask new questions in comments. You're also supposed to upvote and/or accept answers that you find useful. It's not a forum, or a free help desk.